# What are the best tool to generate an RTP session?

Tags: multimedia, tools, sip

I want to generate some RTP traffic between Windows and Ubuntu and capture the packets using Wireshark. This is for study purpose.

What tools can I use for generating RTP traffic. Whatever I tried requires SIP. Is there any tools which don't require SIP, can be used to Generate RTP (audio/video...whatever). ?

I am basically looking for an easy way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried Video Lan Client(VLC)

http://www.videolan.org/streaming-features.html